# How do I make the Super key open the activities overview in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, 20.04, activities-overview

I've upgraded two laptops to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  On one of them pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> (aka the Windows Logo key) opens the *Activities* overview.  On the other one it doesn't, and I have to use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

The main difference between the laptops is that one uses Ubuntu on Wayland (where <kbd>Super</kbd> works fine), and the other one uses Ubuntu on Xorg (where <kbd>Super</kbd> doesn't work).

How do I make <kbd>Super</kbd> work on both laptops?

Comment: I've the same issue. I couldn't find a launchpad bug report of it as for now. That should be your first step probably:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ As I'm writing I discovered that it works now. You can set the key responsible for the overview in Gnome Tweaks "Keyboard & Mouse > Overview Shortcut". Maybe switch between Left and Right super and reboot. Seems to have worked for me.

Comment: It seems like a Gnome issue https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1144. In short, the Super key works correctly only for the first and fourth keyboard layouts. So the workaround would be to set your primary layout as the first one.

Comment: Oooh, that could be it!  There's only one keyboard layout on my laptop where Super works, but two on the other one.

Would you convert your comment to an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is related to a recent Gnome [issue](http://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1144). Currently using the <kbd>Super</kbd> key for the *Activities overview* works only on the first and fourth keyboard layouts, in Xorg sessions.

As a workaround until this gets fixed, you should set your primary layout as the first one.

Comment: Third layout (of three) does not work either for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure sticky keys is disabled on the accesibility section in settings

Comment: Hello and welcome to AU. Could you develop your answer a little bit?  Specify how to diable the 'sticky keys' in which settings, for example.

Comment: It's "Settings > Accessibility > Typing Assist > Sticky Keys". 
And indeed it does help. Super key is now showing the Overview for me. 

Thanks @edgardo-escalante!